# How do I create a .desktop file to launch eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, .desktop

When I create a .desktop file to launch eclipse (latest build with JDK 1.8 support) I get the following error:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/dean/bin/eclipse-standard-luna-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

Why does it try to find the JRE under the directory where the eclipse binary is?

I can launch Eclipse from the command line, and I can pin it to the launcher and it works.  Why is the .desktop file so confused about what it is supposed to do?

Here is my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse JDK 1.8
Comment=Eclipse
Exec=/home/dean/bin/eclipse-standard-luna-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/dean/bin/eclipse-standard-luna-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

The problem I'm having is not what was asked in [the question linked above as a duplice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198527/desktop-link-to-eclipse).  My issue is because my PATH to the JDK is set in my .bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied the following block from within the `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then` statement:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc_" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

I've also tried without the if statement:

```
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

but Eclipse fails with the same error message in both cases.  Apparently `HOME` isn't set when lightdm runs `~/.profile`.

Explicitly setting the path in `~/.profile` works, but I want to keep my PATH and my other Bash features (aliases, functions) in the same file.

The solution is to set the `PATH` on the `Exec=env PATH=$PATH:...` line in eclipse.desktop.  Nothing I've tried works to start IntelliJ from a desktop icon, however.

Given that you are reinventing the Linux GUI experience with Unity maybe it's time to leave the error prone series of scripts behind and use something that is less error prone and easier to use.  The scripts would still have to be there for bash shells, but the Unity desktop could be independent of them.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.

The next eclipse.desktop file works in Ubuntu 14.06 x64.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=/home/ivan/Eclipse/eclipse -vm /home/ivan/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
Icon=/home/ivan/Eclipse/icon.xpm
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

I didn't modify the **eclipse.ini**

Another solution is to modify the **eclipse.ini** file without modify your  **eclipse.desktop**

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/home/ivan/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.

More info: [Wiki eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Answer (score 1):

The output does say that it searched in the PATH too:

```
No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
...
java in your current PATH
```

You said you can launch `eclipse` from a terminal: In this case I would say that your `java` is installed to a non-standard directory, which is added to your PATH by a terminal startup script (bashrc, zshrc, etc.) but it is not added to your session when you login. So when you are in a terminal session your PATH is different from the one which is used when the .desktop file is invoked.

To troubleshoot this case:

- To see where `java` is installed: `which java`
- Check your `~/.profile` if the correct PATH with the `java` directory is set in it. If the correct path is only set in `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc. then it is possible that those scripts are not invoked on login, so the PATH is not set correctly.  Also if you have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` you have to check those too. <sub>If you provide these files we can look into this whether this is your problem.</sub>

If you can't solve it this way, you can always modify the PATH directly in the .desktop file with `env PATH= ...`

Comment: That's exactly my issue then.  I set the PATH to the JDK in .bashrc.  Looking at the docs for a .desktop file the PATH entry seems to do something else.  Is there a way to set the system PATH in .desktop?

Comment: After some Googling I found that the solution is to change the Exec line like this:  `Exec=env PATH=/home/dean/bin/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH /home/dean/bin/eclipse-standard-luna-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/eclipse`  The docs for the .desktop file were no help.

Comment: The same modification to the Exec=... line does not work for launching IntelliJ via the idea.sh file, however.

Comment: @DeanSchulze Yes, `Exec=env PATH= ...`, that's what I meant in my last line. Normally you would like to set up PATH in .profile, not .bashrc. The .profile file is parsed by the login shell so it will set up PATH correctly when you login, and then there will be no need for the `env` workaround. On Debian/Ubuntu .profile sources .bashrc, so this shouldn't be a problem, but maybe your .profile is not doing it, so check it. Or you have a .bash_profile or .bash_login file which overrides the .profile settings.

Comment: @DeanSchulze So to sum up, set your PATH in .profile (or .bash_profile or .bash_login if you have one of those files) not in .bashrc, or make sure that .bashrc is sourced by the aforementioned files. If you set it up this way, your PATH should be correct for the .desktop files too, and there will be no need for "tricking".

Comment: The `/root/.profile` only sources the `~/.bashrc` when `if [ "$BASH" ];` returns true.  The Unity desktop would have to appear as a Bash shell for my .bashrc to get sourced by .profile.

Comment: @DeanSchulze Yes, I know that. But I always thought that `lightdm` sources `~/.profile` as the default shell of the user, which is by default `bash`. But as I never had problems with these things it was just an assumption. Indeed, looking at [this bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1252456), `lightdm` sources `~/.profile` as `sh`, so `.bashrc` is not sourced. But to be short: Just declare your PATH in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` and everything will be in order. (I don't know why you are referring to `/root/.profile`, you need your users `~/.profile`.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple method.

Open Gedit or Text Editor. Add:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/testrule/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/testrule/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
```

Save in desktop as `eclipse.desktop`.

Right Click on the `eclipse.desktop` file > click properties > click Permissions                      tab >> Click the **check box** of Execute