# Why some of my applications missing from Synapse search?

Tags: search, synapse

Mostly application that is installed in `/opt` cannot be searched anymore using Synapse.

It used to be there. But after sometimes I they are gone.

I am using latest LTS Ubuntu Mate and installed Synapse from the `sudo apt-get install synapse`.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: _“latest”_ Please use the version number which is an absolute reference forever. The question may remain here for decades. Another time-related question: _When_ was it there? Haven’t you upgraded your OS in between, for example?

Comment: Can you give an example of which application it didn't show?

Comment: @Anwar, Sublime Text 3 and Chromium used to be there in Synapse. But not anymore. I installed Sublime Text 3 using .deb and Chromium using package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synapse relies on `.desktop` files  in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` for the application being shown in it's search list.
If it doesn't find a .desktop file in those locations, it will not show that application if you search it.

I have both Google Chrome and Sublime Text installed and synapse shows them in search. To test, I removed sublime texts `.desktop` file. The result was **synapse stopped showing Sublime in the search result** after removal of it's. desktop file.

I belive, your application doesn't have a .desktop file.  If your application doesn't have a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` directory or if you removed that file at some point of time, You can create one by hand. Check these questions 
to have info for it.

- [How do I create a .desktop file to launch eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418407/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-file-to-launch-eclipse)
- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)